# Изменить цены с listbox

Tags: html

Здравствуйте. Как можно это сделать? сайт DLE  [ссылка сайта](https://steam.az/odenis-kartlari/14-google-play-gift-card.html)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

В коде на данной странице поменяй эту сроку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а как сделать, когда открываются новости автоматические выбрать первые пакет (google play10$)  ?